# Running sails.js project locally has wiped production DB

Tags: mysql, sails.js, cleardb

We are trying to figure out how our production DB was wiped recently: a team member ran the local dev build using the production database url as env variables. The dev build drops all data and repopulates the tables with mock data. I am just confused because the team member did not specifically set the NODE_ENV to our `heroku` production environment, so would have thought our dev config file would be used, and the live database url never actually used by sails.

Here is our development config file (`/config/env/development.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  connections: {
    localMySql: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'correct',
      database: 'foch_testing'
    },
  },
  models: {
    connection: 'localMySql',
    migrate: 'drop'
  },
...
}
```

To me, looking at that config, it looks like it would have specified the foch_testing database to use whilst in development mode, but we cannot think what else could have caused the wipe.

To confirm, the live database was not called `foch_testing`.

UPDATE WITH PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT

And the live database is only accessed explicitly in the production environment:

```
module.exports = {
  connections: {
    mysql: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
    }
  },
  models: {
    connection: 'mysql',
    migrate: 'safe'
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try not to keep production database accessible directly from work network.

Comment: You sure you run it with proper NODE_ENV ?

Comment: So it turns out the development server was run with production db environment variables. It was clearly not a wise move, but I don't understand why they would have been used given the NODE_ENV wasn't set, so the default development config should surely have been used?